# Adjust centroids spatial polygons using sf

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I have a shapefile of local government regions. I use `sf_read()` to import it into R as an SF object.  I want to compute the distance between the local government regions. `st_centroid()` gives me polygon centroids and I can compute distance using `st_distance()`.

```
regions <- st_read("~/Downloads/regions.shp")

regions_with_centroids <- st_centroid(regions)

extract_centroids <- regions_with_centroids %>% 
                           st_drop_geometry() %>% 
                           as_tibble() %>%
                           select(region_name, centroid)
# create edge list

edge_list <- extract_centroids %>%
                           select(region_name) %>%
                           expand(from = region_name, to = region_name) %>% 
                           filter(from < to) %>%
                           left_join(extract-centroids, by = c("from" = "region_name) %>%
                           rename(from_centroid = centroid) %>%
                           left_join(extract-centroids, by = c("to" = "region_name) %>%
                           rename(to_centroid = centroid) %>%
                           mutate(distance = st_distance(from_centroid, to_centroid)
```

However, I really want to analyze the commuting distance between major urban areas in each government region. I need to shift the centroids to the population "centre of gravity".

I can use a shapefile of census enumerator areas to help me with this. The enumerator areas are sized by population. Using `st_intersection()` I can intersect the enumerator areas with the government regions. This gives me sub-regions within each government region. I can compute centroids for all the sub-regions. Grouping by region, I can compute the mean centroid for all the sub-regions in a region. The mean `centroid = "centre of gravity"`, which gives a more realistic commute distance between regions.

```
regions <- st_read("~/Downloads/regions.shp")

ea <- st_read("~/Downloads/enumerator_areas.shp")

intersected <- st_intersection(regions, ea)

sub_region_centroids <- st_centroids(intersected)
```

Where I run into difficulty is how to find the mean centroid. Grouping by region is not working.

```
mean_centroid <- sub_region_centroids %>%
                          group_by(region_name) %>%
                          summarise(mean_centroid = mean(geometry))

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(geometry) :
  the argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Where am I going wrong?

I also do not know how to add the mean centroid back to the original region's object.

I hope someone can assist me.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can include a small data example

Comment: Could you use a convex (or concave) hull around the sub-region centroids, and use the centroid of that hull?

Comment: @Wimpel I need to figure out how to do this for complex spatial objects. I am new to spatial analysis in R. I can provide a link to data.

Comment: Maybe this question has what you are looking for? https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6025

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computing a population weighted average of multiple centroids is an interesting problem.

You can consider approach like this - where I calculate the weighted centroid of three cities in North Carolina (to make use of the well known & much loved `nc.shp` file that ships with `{sf}`).

The workflow uses `tidyr::uncount()` to first multiply the city points per population, the (many) multiplied points are then united to a single multipoint feature. And multipoint features have defined `sf::st_centroid()` operation (QED). The final `sf::st_as_sf()` is just a polish.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# included with sf package
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

# dramatis personae; population as per Wikipedia
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                  x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                  y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333),
                  population = c(467665, 299035, 115451)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

# a quick overview of facts on ground 
ggplot() +
   geom_sf(data = shape) + # polygon of North Carolina
   geom_sf(data = cities, color = "red") # 3 cities
```

[image: three cities in NC]

```
# unweighted centroid / a baseline    
plain_center <- cities %>% 
  st_geometry() %>% # pull just geometry
  st_combine() %>%  # from many points to a single multipoint
  st_centroid() %>% # compute centroid of the multipoint
  st_as_sf() # make it a sf object again

# the fun is here!!
center_of_centers <- cities %>% 
  tidyr::uncount(population) %>% # multiply rows according to population
  st_geometry() %>% # pull just geometry
  st_combine() %>%  # from many points to a single multipoint
  st_centroid() %>% # compute centroid of the multipoint
  st_as_sf() # make it a sf object again

# finished result
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape, color = "gray75") + # polygon of North Carolina
  geom_sf(data = cities, color = "red") + # 3 cities
  geom_sf(data = plain_center, color = "green") + # unweighted center
  geom_sf(data = center_of_centers, color = "blue", pch = 4) # population weighted center
```

[image: corrected map / with weighted and unweighted centroids both]

Comment: Thanks @Jindra!

Comment: @aterhorst on second thought - there has been a logical fault in my code; I have mistaken `sf::st_union()` and `sf::st_combine()`  (an easy mistake to make, unfortunately) and my earlier answer showed _unweighted_ center (the weighted center has to be farther from Wilmington and closer to Raleigh, just look at the population numbers). My apologies, it is corrected now.

Answer (score 4):

Following @Jindra Lacko's nice example, here is how it can be done taking the weighted mean of the lat and long.

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# weighted mean of lat and long
center_weighted <- cities %>%
  mutate(lon = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,1],
         lat = sf::st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  summarize(across(c(lon, lat), weighted.mean, w = population)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)


# plot it
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape, color = "gray75") + 
  geom_sf(data = cities, color = "red") + 
  geom_sf(data = center_weighted, color = "blue", pch = 4)
```

[image]

---

Data

```r
# set up example data
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 
cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Wilmington"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -77.912222),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 34.223333),
                     population = c(467665, 299035, 115451)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)
```

Comment: Interesting; and delivers seemingly the same (I haven't checked, but the map looks pretty much the same) result as my code - at much, much less CPU resources. I am trying to think of any issue, and with the exception of the island of Fiji - which straddles the antimeridean and is a known trouble maker - can't think of any. Points have it easy...

Comment: In a comment above I stuck a link to a question on GIS stack exchange where someone suggested this method. The one thing that is recommended there that I did not do here is convert from lat/long to a projected X/Y coordinate system. Using lat/long seems approximately the same in this example, but perhaps the difference becomes more obvious when averaging points at a larger spatial scale.